# Datatype of a Collection Initializer

Tags: c#, collections

## Background

When creating a collection, we can do a rather verbose population...

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.Add("a");
a.Add("b");
```

or we can use a simpler [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) as follows...

```
Foo a = new Foo() {"a", "b"};
```

Of course, this is assuming you've implemented the [appropriate methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) as defined by `IEnumerable`.  Funny thing is, the [ienumerable.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/ienumerable.cs,9be451ac13d86a97) source code doesn't say anything about `Add()`, let alone what the datatype is that's being passed to the method.  There's some ["spooky action at a distance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance) going on here.

> As a side-note, it's always a bad sign when the datatype alluded to
>   has a space in it (which is illegal for datatypes). The C#
>   documentation seems to indicate this for our [`Collection Initializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) (if
>   that is what it is).

Consider a more complex `Foo` which contains `key:value` pairs...

```
Foo a = new Foo() {
    {"alpha": "Hello"},
    {"beta": "World"}
};
```

[The syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer) certainly *looks* like a `Dictionary`, but when setting a breakpoint at the enclosed `Foo.Add()` method, the only thing it operates on are *individual entries* in that list.

Furthermore, a single entry (such as `{"alpha": "Hello"}`) isn't explicitly passed to the method; the individual elements in that "array"(?) are applied to the method as individual arguments.

```
public void Add(string key, string value) { ... }
```

C# is touted as a strongly typed language, yet here we never declare the types of our input.  I can only assume that the compiler (?) searches the class for an appropriate `Add` method with a matching signature and calls that, parceling out individual values, one at a time.

"Ok", that might pass fast-and-loose for the compiler, but what if we want to implement a `Foo.Append()` method which takes a `Collection Initializer` and adds that to the end of our Foo instance?  It'd be nice to simply write

```
a.Append({
    {"gamma": "I Like"},
    {"delta": "turtles."}
});
```

However, this is rejected by the compiler.  One could imagine instantiating a `new Dictionary()` with the `key:value` pairs just to pass to our method... but why bother?  Especially if its just going to be disposed of, to be inducted into our objective `Foo` dataset.

## Questions

1. Can someone explain what's actually happening with `Collection Initializer`?
2. How can `Append()` be elegantly resolved without unnecessary object instantiations?

Comment: Any chance we will ever find out what `Foo` is?  You say it is a collection, but it doesnt appear to be generic, but you can put integers or strings in it.  Also `Enumerable` (also not generic) is for enumerating.  `Collection<T>` on the other hand does have an `Add` method (and other collection related methods and properties)

Comment: I've intentionally tried to omit an explicit definition of `Foo`, as I don't consider its design to be the focus of the question.  Suffice to say, imagine a class which has some sort of internal storage, and is an implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: All an object initializer needs is for the type to implement IEnumerable<T> _and_ to have an Add() method (there's no Add on IEnumerable<T>, all the compiler cares about is for the pattern to match).  As for the "data type", well, in your example it's an int because 0 or 1 are ints, and as long as your Add() method can take those as a parameter, it'll compile. This is similar to how foreach doesn't actually need IEnumerable, only GetEnumerator(), or how destructuring only requires a Deconstruct method. The compiler generates code for you and if it compiles, it 's valid.

Comment: Implementing `IEnumerable` alone doesnt make it a collection.  Having "internal storage" means it *consumes* or uses a collection but doesnt mean it *is* a collection.  [Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)